# Using AutoHotKey to Select Listbox Items

Tags: listbox, automation, autohotkey

I'm trying to automate some work in a 3rd party application (Cognos) using AutoHotKey.  There are two listboxes, and basically you double click on the left box and it populates the box on the right.  I want to select 'n' number of items in a particular, specified order.  Basically the pseudo-script would be something like:

```
down 4
doubleclick
up 2
doubleclick
```

Up & down is not a problem, but I can't get double click to work.  I tried two "MouseClick, left" but that requires the mouse to be at the correct position.  If this is the solution, how do I move the mouse to the listbox's item that has focus?

And before anyone asks... I tried alternatives to double clicking, such as the enter key, but enter = "ok" since it's technically in a large dialogue box.

If anyone has an alternative to AutoHotKey that'd be appreciated too.  I tried VBS & "sendkeys" first, but double click really seemed not do-able.

Thanks

Comment: Try `ControlGetFocus` in order to get the focused control and then `ControlClick` on that control.

Comment: -- did you try MouseMove, Click, Sleep, Click -- what is the name of the control, is it ListBox or something else -- is there an arrow button you can click, that would move items from one listbox to the other
-- ControlGetPos can get the position of a control -- if AccViewer can identify individual ListBox items then you could use Acc.ahk to find the listbox item coordinates prior to MouseMove